# Steps to call Graph API from Simple Azure bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for simple working code snippet to call Microsoft Graph API from any bot. I want to get information through graph API calls. It would be great if I can get step by step guide to follow reg how to call Microsoft Teams Graph API. I am struggling to find exact steps to accomplish below:

1) Exact code snippet to call Graph API from Azure bot code
2) Handle Authentication in step 1)
3) Process data returned back in bot code

Thanks in advance,

Anu

Comment: You can make HTTP requests to the Graph API from within your bot's code for both [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview) and [requesting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials). You can then process it however you'd like within the bot's code

Comment: If you can provide additional detail and what programming language you're using, I can probably help you further.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I just sent you email on  v-micric@microsoft.com. I use c#. I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph is a great sample to show how to connect bot to Microsoft Graph. However, there are a few bugs with the sign-in and sending mail I am having trouble with both.

Comment: hey Thanks for pointers! I am looking into it now , will try to run locally and let you know if I encounter issues in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I answered OP via email, but for posterity's sake, have included a summary of my answer here. The question ended up being more conceptual, than "how do I fix this", so the answer mostly entails documentation and samples.

We actually have a [sample bot that uses MS Graph API](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph).

It uses OAuth to log the user in, with Azure Active Directory (AADv2) as the OAuth provider.
To make the requests, it uses [Microsoft.Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), which you can use in your bot as well.

If you’d prefer to use the REST API instead, there’s [some good documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) for getting all the info you want from Teams. There are also [Graph SDKs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started).

There are also some Azure Bot Service docs [specific to authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript).